# How to remove Exo Preffered Applications (of Xfce) from Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, xfce

I recently installed the Dolphin file manager to try it on Ubuntu.
I then removed it and I now want to uninstall [Exo Preferred Applications](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/exo/preferred-applications) which I installed to make Dolphin as a default file manager.

I now want to uninstall Exo Preferred Application from Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install Exo Preferred Applications in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you installed `exo-utils` in your **Ubuntu** distribution. To remove it, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge exo-utils
```

---

**NOTE: if you have Xubuntu, or Xfce (which means** `exo-utils` **comes by default), then removing it might broke your desktop environment!**

In case you are unsure about your distribution, type:

```
cat /var/log/installer/media-info
```

If you do not have Xubuntu, but you are not sure whether you have Xfce, type:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

If you get `XFCE` in the latter, or `Xubuntu` in the former, then it is better not to uninstall `exo-utils`.

If you want to see why this might be problematic, type:

```
sudo apt-get -s purge exo-utils
```

This command simulates (hence the `-s`) the purging of the package, without actually removing it. If you explore the output once it's finished, you will see this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  exo-utils* orage* thunar* thunar-archive-plugin* thunar-media-tags-plugin*
  thunar-volman* xfce4-cpugraph-plugin* xfce4-dict* xfce4-mailwatch-plugin*
  xfce4-netload-plugin* xfce4-notes-plugin* xfce4-panel* xfce4-places-plugin*
  xfce4-power-manager-plugins* xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin*
  xfce4-systemload-plugin* xfce4-terminal* xfce4-verve-plugin*
  xfce4-weather-plugin* xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin* xfce4-xkb-plugin*
  xfdesktop4* xubuntu-core* xubuntu-desktop*
```

Which means you are wipping out the whole Xfce desktop environment.